# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0, Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a grocery list creator in Flutter. I made a class, GroceryList, that takes the title, the reminder day, the list of ingredients, and the list of the number of ingredients as parameters. I am currently coding the "Finish" button, which will take all of the lists information and put it in a grocery list class. Here is the relevant code:

```
  final curTitle = new TextEditingController();
  int countings = 0;
  List<String> finalIngs = [];
  List<String> numfinalIngs = [];
  String _reminderDay = "Sunday";
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint(curTitle.text);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("New Grocery List"),
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Colors.white),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ListsPage()),
              );
            },
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.white),
              onPressed: () {
                if (finalIngs[0].isNotEmpty &&
                    numfinalIngs[0].isNotEmpty &&
                    curTitle.text.isNotEmpty) {
                  for (int i = 0; i < _newListIngs.length; i++) {
                    finalIngs.add(_newListIngs[i].text);
                    debugPrint(finalIngs[i]);
                    numfinalIngs.add(_newlistnumIngs[i].text);
                    debugPrint(numfinalIngs[i]);
                  }
                  GroceryList cur;
                  cur.title = curTitle.text;
                  cur._reminderDay = _reminderDay;
                  for (int i = 0; i < finalIngs.length; i++) {
                    cur.ingredients.add(finalIngs[i]);
                    cur.numIngs.add(numfinalIngs[i]);
                  }
                } else {
                  showIngAlert(BuildContext context) {
                    Widget okButton = FlatButton(
                      child: Text("OK"),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    );

                    // set up the AlertDialog
                    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
                      content: Text(
                          "Please fill all blank spaces, and add as needed."),
                      actions: [
                        okButton,
                      ],
                    );

                    // show the dialog
                    showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return alert;
                      },
                    );
                  }

                  showIngAlert(context);
                }
                _newListIngs.clear();
                _newlistnumIngs.clear();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
  }
```

There's a lot more to the class, but I got rid of it for the sake of neatness. I am getting the error shown above, and I know what it means and why it's there, but I don't know how I should fix it. I mean, I don't know what to do for a permanent solution, rather than getting rid of this error. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of lists so I am not sure which one has the problem but have you tried checking if they're empty before trying to get what its inside

```
if(finalIngs.isNotEmpty && numfinalIngs.isNotEmpty && 
      (finalIngs[0]?.isNotEmpty ?? false) && //What if the Strings are null?
      (numfinalIngs[0]?.isNotEmpty ?? false) && //What if the Strings are null?
      curTitle.text.isNotEmpty)
  ....
```

Obviously if the lists are empty the other conditions have to be false, but they won't run because it's not needed (the `if` stops when it finds the first false when using double &) so it won't show an error

Comment: That...semes to have worked. I'm not getting the error anymore, and for that, I am grateful. Unfourtanetly my alert doesn't seem to work, so I'm working to fix that and see if I've completed this part of the project. Thanks so much!

Comment: Yeah, that. I installed a plugin to make the whole thing easier, so now that's working for me. If you want to know, I recall it was called rflutter_alert

Answer (score 1):

I have a guess but i can't sure. I see `final curTitle = new TextEditingController();` and I see this assigned
`GroceryList cur;   cur.title = curTitle.text;`
But i can't see TextField text for TextEditingController or any title for curTitle i think it is null. I hope i could help. Sorry if my answer is mistake because i am new :) Have a good days for you,developer!

Comment: I do actually have a textField, but I guess I got rid of it to clear up the post. Thanks for trying to help.